# Select (or split) column from SQLCMD output

Tags: json, powershell, sqlcmd, powershell-1.0

How do I select the columns from `SQLCMD` output in PowerShell v1? I'm trying to make JSON output using `Write-Output` in PowerShell v1.

Query output at the end.

`$_` returns both columns. If only we could use `$_.name` and `$_.jobid`, but they both returns empty lines. Fixing this would be the preferred solution.

Here is the PowerShell command:

```
Write-Output '{"data":[';
(SQLCMD -S 'x.x.x.x' -U 'user' -P 'passwors' -i "C:\query.sql" -W) | %{
    try {
        ($coma + '{"{#JOBID}":"' + $_  + '",' + '"{#JOBNAME}":"' + $_ + '"}');
        $coma=',';
    } catch {}
};
Write-Output "]}"
```

What it returns:

```json
{"data":[
,{"{#JOBID}":"12345-aaaa-1234-5678-000000000000000 Clear DB entries","{#JOBNAME}":"12345-aaaa-1234-5678-000000000000000 Clear DB entries"}
,{"{#JOBID}":"12345-bbbb-1234-5678-000000000000000 TempLog DB","{#JOBNAME}":"12345-bbbb-1234-5678-000000000000000 TempLog DB"}
]}
```

What I expect:

```json
{"data":[
,{"{#JOBID}":"12345-aaaa-1234-5678-000000000000000","{#JOBNAME}":"Clear DB entries"}
,{"{#JOBID}":"12345-bbbb-1234-5678-000000000000000","{#JOBNAME}":"TempLog DB"}
]}
```

I'm not sure how to use split with tab delimiter `($_ -split "`t") for both `job_id` and `name`. My attempts either returned both column names as one and in some cases it returned empty.

Here is the query and its output on a command line:

```
PS C:\> SQLCMD -S 'x.x.x.x' -U 'user' -P 'password' -i "C:\query.sql" -W

job_id name
12345-aaaa-1234-5678-000000000000000 Clear DB entries
12345-bbbb-1234-5678-000000000000000 TempLog DB
(2 rows affected)
```

I know about `ConvertTo-Json` on version 3, but I want to get it working on PowerShell v1 so it'd be helpful to those who can't upgrade for whatever reason.

Comment: Instead of `$_.name` have you tried `$_["name"]`?

Comment: That returns empty as well

Comment: what does `$_ | Get-Member` return?

Comment: If I assign sqlcmd output to` $var1` and then run `$var1 | select $_ | get-member` I get this output. https://imgur.com/a/McJ1U    It seems like the whole sqlcmd output is saved as text based table so maybe properties for it? I'm not sure

Comment: There is absolutely NO valid reason for using PowerShell v1. All currently supported Windows versions can run at least PowerShell v3. Even Windows XP and Server 2003 can run PowerShell v2 at the very least. Upgrade now.

Comment: This isn't about version, just trying to get something done through write-host. If fixed, I could post it to the community where they can use either version 1 or version 3 method. I really did not wanted any comments about version 1 and that's why I specifically mentioned that I'm aware of it. I do recommend version 3 to others but this  1.0  issue seems simple if we could just find a way to split the data. Rest of the format is JSON ready. Do you have any inputs for $_.name issue?

Comment: `$var | Get-Member` (you don't want the `Select-Object`)

Comment: It is the same output as Select-Object $_.  I first tried without select-object but get-member was same for both

Comment: Also if I try `$var1 | select name` it returns empty. If I don't specify name or $_ it returns all lines. Note: the output shown above shows extra spaces as if its like tab, but in reality the output has only one space separating JOBID and JOBNAME. I'll correct the output in the post

Comment: Can you think of someway to set headers or properties when assigning  `$var=(sqlcmd -s x.x.x. ..)` so it can be called with `$_.property`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another method, seems reliable. Thanks to [Bacon Bits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49285349/9489836)  answer.

```
$coma=''; Write-Output '{"data":[';
(SQLCMD -S 'x.x.x.x' -U 'user' -P 'password' -i "C:\query.sql" -W -m 1 -s `"`t`") | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter "`t" |  Select-Object -Skip 1 | %{
    try {
        ($coma + '{"{#JOBID}":"' + $_.job_id  + '",' + '"{#JOBNAME}":"' + $_.name + '"}');
        $coma=',';
    } catch {}
};
Write-Output "]}"
```

If your data contains tabs, you'll need a different separator. The Select-Object -Skip 1 is to skip the underline row that sqlcmd always creates below the header.

Also be aware that you should use the -w parameter on sqlcmd to prevent any incorrect wrapping. Also beware that null values are always output as a literal string NULL.

Again `Powershell v3` or `Invoke-SQLcmd` is recommended over this method.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I have come up with is to use `($_ -split ' ')[1..100]` for second column `#JOBNAME` and `($_ -split ' ')[0]` for first column `#JOBID`.

Note: This only works because the `JOBID` column values is phrased as one single word. It doesn't work for other queries if the first column has random number of words.

Here is the final command and output :

```
$coma=''; Write-Output '{"data":[';
(SQLCMD -S 'x.x.x.x' -U 'user' -P 'passwors' -i "C:\query.sql" -W) | %{
    try {
        ($coma + '{"{#JOBID}":"' + ($_ -split ' ')[0]  + '",' + '"{#JOBNAME}":"' + ($_ -split ' ')[1..100] + '"}');
        $coma=',';
    } catch {}
};
Write-Output "]}"
```

Output:

```json
{"data":[
,{"{#JOBID}":"12345-aaaa-1234-5678-000000000000000","{#JOBNAME}":"Clear DB entries"}
,{"{#JOBID}":"12345-bbbb-1234-5678-000000000000000","{#JOBNAME}":"TempLog DB"}
]}
```

There is also **Invoke-SQLcmd** method but it takes 30 seconds to add snap-in and 2 seconds to execute query.

```
    Add-PSSnapin SqlServerCmdletSnapin100; $coma=''; Write-Output '{"data":[';
    (Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance 'x.x.x.x' -username 'user' -password 'password' -inputfile "C:\query.sql") | %{
        try {
    ($coma + '{"{#JOBID}":"' + $_.job_id  + '",' + '"{#JOBNAME}":"' + $_.name + '"}');
    $coma=',';
        } catch {}
    };
    Write-Output "]}"
```

If you have `Powershell v3` then you could just use `Sqlcmd... | ConvertTO-Json`